# How to add first number in row in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say we have the following df

```
letter   number
a         10
b         11
```

and I wanted to add only the first number in a column. How would you do that

Result

= number column should have a sum of two (**1**0 + **1**1) = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faster option is to get the `substring`, convert to numeric and get the `sum`

```
with(df, sum(as.numeric(substring(number, 1, 1))))
[1] 2
```

Or we may use

```
with(df, sum(number %/% 10))
[1] 2
```

Or as @rg255 mentioned in the comments, if the number of digits can be different (other than the 2 digit mentioned in the example)

```
with(df, sum(number %/% 10^(nchar(number)-1)))
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that the second option there works only for values between 10 and 99.

Comment: Okay sweet. For the first option, if I wanted to add the second numbers together, would I do with(df, sum(as.numeric(substring(number, 2,2))))

Comment: @Dylan with `substring`, you can extract digits from any positions or a range i.e. `substring(number, 2, 4)` etc

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `x` here for you column (e.g. `df$v2`). This creates a list of the digits within each element, then extracts the first and sums them.

```
sum(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ""), function(i){as.numeric(i[1])}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(111)

df <- tibble(letter = letters[1:10], number = sample(1:100, 10))

summarise(df, sum_first = str_sub(number, 1, 1) %>%
                           as.numeric() %>% 
                            sum() )
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   sum_first
#>       <dbl>
#> 1        52
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>